# Sort ul by multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a ul list with li-s..

Each li contains three attributes: attr-x, attr-y and attr-z.

I am trying to sort the ul according to:

top group is attr-x=true.
bottom group is attr-x=false.

for each one of both groups:
Sort by attr-y (biggest numbers to smallest numbers).

After that, **ONLY** if there are elements with equal attr-y, sort by attr-z.

Examples:

```
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="20">a</div>
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="3" data-z="25">b</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="25">c</div>
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="5" data-z="20">d</div>
```

first sort (data-x=true in top, data-x=false in bottom):

```
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="3" data-z="25">b</div>
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="5" data-z="20">d</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="20">a</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="25">c</div>
```

second sort (for each sub groups, sort by data-y):

```
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="5" data-z="20">d</div>
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="3" data-z="25">b</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="20">a</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="25">c</div>
```

Third sort (if data-y is equal in sub group, sort by data-z):

```
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="5" data-z="20">d</div>
<div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="3" data-z="25">b</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="25">c</div>
<div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="20">a</div>
```

This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5uq2qrte/

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You changed `data-z` values for a and c in first and last example, is that error?

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I fixed it and am checking it again..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` like this.

```js
var sorted = $('.testWrapper div').sort(function(a, b) {
  return ($(b).data('x') - $(a).data('x')) || ($(b).data('y') - $(a).data('y')) || ($(b).data('z') - $(a).data('z'))
})

$(".testWrapper").html(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testWrapper">
  <div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="20">a</div>
  <div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="3" data-z="25">b</div>
  <div class="test" data-x="false" data-y="7" data-z="25">c</div>
  <div class="test" data-x="true" data-y="5" data-z="20">d</div>
</div>
```