# Sort li by data attr and parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list similar to this that I want to sort. It needs to sort the class parent-category by data-order. If there are any child-categories, get the parentcategoryid from the child, and match that to its parents category id, and sort all its children by data-order.

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>
```

So the result should be:

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>
```

Currently I have this:

```
category.sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).data('order') - $(b).data('order');
});

category.appendTo('.categories');
```

Which sorts all the li elements by data-order without respect to the parent-child relationship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ul by multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880489/sort-ul-by-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach for this will be mapping the `data-*` values to numbers and then sort using these numbers:

> For a `<li>` item that has the class `parent-category` we assing the value of `data-categoryId * 1000`.

So, next `<li>` items will be mapped to numbers `1000` and `2000` respectively. This also will assure that we can have lots of child categories on every category.

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>
```

> Now, for a `<li>` item that has the class `child-category` we assing the value of `(data-parentCategoryId * 1000) + data-order`.

So, next `<li>` items will be mapped to numbers `1001` and `1002` respectively.

```
<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>
```

And finally we use the `sort()` over these generated numbers. In summary, you can see this logic implemented on the next code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var orderedCats = $(".category").sort((a, b) =>
    {
        var aCat = $(a).hasClass("parent-category") ? $(a).data("categoryid") : $(a).data("parentcategoryid");
        var aOrder = $(a).hasClass("parent-category") ? 0 : $(a).data("order");
        var bCat = $(b).hasClass("parent-category") ? $(b).data("categoryid") : $(b).data("parentcategoryid");
        var bOrder = $(b).hasClass("parent-category") ? 0 : $(b).data("order");

        return (aCat * 1000 + aOrder) - (bCat * 1000 + bOrder);
    });

    $(".wrapper").html(orderedCats);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='1'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this way:

```
category.sort(function(a, b) {
  if ($(a).data('categoryId') != $(b).data('categoryId'))
    return $(a).data('categoryId') - $(b).data('categoryId')
  else
    return $(a).data('order') - $(b).data('order');
});
```

This starts with the category being sorted, then sorts according to order. This is just a starting point and you can change it as needed.